# Android List in SharedPreference

Tags: java, android

I am trying to edit values from List in SharedPreferences but someting is going wrong.

My SharedPreference is:

```
public class StepsData {
    static SharedPreferences data;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    static final int VALUE_KEY = 0;
    static final List<String> LIST_KEY= new Vector<String>();
}
```

I use SharedPref by:

```
StepsData.data = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);
StepsData.editor = StepsData.data.edit();
```

if I want to edit or get value from VALUE_KEY everything works by:

```
int step = StepsData.data.getInt(String.valueOf(VALUE_KEY), 0);
editor.putInt(String.valueOf(VALUE_KEY), 0).apply();
```

but I have a problem with using List, my code for get value is:

```
List<String> myList = (List<String>) data.getStringSet(String.valueOf(LIST_KEY),null);
```

and for delete:

```
List<String> clearList = new Vector<String>();
editor.putStringSet(String.valueOf(LIST_KEY), (Set<String>) clearList).apply();
```

but there is a NullPointerException. What is the best way to use something like ".clear()" on List from SharedPreference and how is is possible to get values from this List and size?

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong with your code. First, the `LIST_KEY` just needs to be a `String` not a `List`. Second, shared preferences accepts `Set<String>` not a `List<String>` as you're doing. However, you can instantiate a `List` with a `Set` and vice versa. `List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(yourStringSet); Set<String> stringSet = new TreeSet<>(yourStringList)`. Just be noted that if the list contains duplicates, they may be reduced to uniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to store List object in SharedPreference then use gson library.
It will use to convert list object into json format and store that json string into sharedPref.
First include this line in gradle file(app level)

> compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

below code is to set the Type to List

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();

Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Now Create list object and convert to json string format using gson object and type

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
//add elements in myList object

String jsonFormat = gson.toJson(myList,listType);  
//adding to sharedPref  
editor.put("list",jsonFormat).apply();
```

Now get the values from sharedPref and convert json string back to List object.

```
//this line will get the json string from sharedPref and will converted into object of type list(specified in listType object) 
List<String> list = gson.fromJson(sharedPref.get("list",""),listType);  
//now modify the list object as par your requirement and again do the same step of converting that list object into jsonFormat.
```

Answer (score 1):

The the following:

Declare `myList` globally:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

For setting value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                     .edit()
                     .putString("number" + i, value + "").commit();         
}
```

For getting value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) {
   myList.add(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                               .getString("number" + i, "0"));
}
```

**NOTE:- `totalSize` is the size of your array**

Comment: what about adding all list into not element by element

Answer (score 1):

why do you using list ?(which is contains duplicate element)
 getting all element from sharedpreference

```
Set<String> set = preference.getStringSet("key", null);

//Set the values
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(listOfExistingScores);
preferenceEditor.putStringSet("key", set);
preferenceEditor.commit();
```

if you must use list check this link also
    https://gist.github.com/cr5315/6200903

Comment: There is one more question. Why I have to use data.getInt(String.valueOf(SOME_INT_KEY), 0); insted of just data.getInt(SOME_INT_KEY, 0); if in shared preferences is static final int SOME_INT_KEY? In every example is second version but I have an error and have to put String.valueof

Comment: shared preference key stored as a string not as a integer,check this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#WriteSharedPreference