# Store Custom Arraylist in SharedPreferences and get it from there?

Tags: java, android, parsing, functional-programming, sharedpreferences

I have a custom model class which implements Parcelable. It contains 3 strings i.e. String id_url,position,type . The complete class is :

```
public class Facebook_Images_Data implements Parcelable {
String id_url;
String position;
String type;
public Facebook_Images_Data(
        String id_url, String position, String type) {

    this.id_url = id_url;
    this.position = position;
    this.type = type;
}

public String getId_url() {
    return id_url;
}

public void setId_url(String id_url) {
    this.id_url = id_url;
}

public String getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(String position) {
    this.position = position;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}


protected Facebook_Images_Data(Parcel in) {
    id_url = in.readString();
    position = in.readString();
    type = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(id_url);
    dest.writeString(position);
    dest.writeString(type);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Facebook_Images_Data> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Facebook_Images_Data>() {
    @Override
    public Facebook_Images_Data createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Facebook_Images_Data(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Facebook_Images_Data[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Facebook_Images_Data[size];
    }
};
}
```

After creating the `ArrayList` of this Model, I need to pass some values to the arraylist. Upto here, its working fine. But how I store this into **sharedpreferences** and fetch it afterwards. (Main motive is to get respective values properly)

Comment: possibly duplicate of this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38307804/5305430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gson library for this.

```
ArrayList<Facebook_Images_Data> listData = new ArrayList<Facebook_Images_Data>(); 
Gson gson = new Gson();
String stringValue = gson.toJson(listData);
prefsEditor.putString("KEY",stringValue);
```

For Fetching :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Facebook_Images_Data> restoredData = gson.fromJson(sharedPreference.getString("KEY"), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Facebook_Images_Data>>() {}.getType());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use gson to achieve this :

```
List<Facebook_Images_Data> yourList = new ArrayList<Facebook_Images_Data>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String valuesString = gson.toJson(yourList);
prefsEditor.putString("YOUR_KEY",valuesString);
```

And to get it back you can use:

```
Type arrayListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Facebook_Images_Data>>(){}.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Facebook_Images_Data> yourList = gson.fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString(YOUR_KEY), arrayListType);
```

Comment: Can you suggest another way without using gson ?

Comment: Another way could be to save a json object or jsonarray as string to the preferences and use the data model you created when you get the json array or json object from the preferences