# Change Resource getString() programmatically

Tags: java, android, getstring

Is there any way to change a R.string programmatically? Because it's throwing an error.

Basically I want to do this:
`String parkAdd = getString(R.string.stg_ParkAddress_+id);`

Because I have hardcoded strings that are changed according ID.

I tried to do this but don't work:

```
String parkAdd = getString(R.string.stg_ParkAddress_1);
parkAdd = parkAdd.replace("1",id);
if (!parkAdd.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
    tvParkAddress.setText(parkAdd);
}
```

Comment: You cannot change the resource values programmaticaly. Basically you cannot change it at runtime

Comment: @AmanGrover but I need a solution to get this, will I need to make a switch?

Comment: But it is not possible to change any resource value at runtime.

Comment: @FilipeOS please go through this it solve your problem using shareperfernce .....http://stackoverflow.com/a/38307804/5305430

Comment: @FilipeOS take a look at Gary's solution. I am not 100% sure it'll work, but it seems the only way if at all possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The R.string.xxx is actually a constant and the value can't be appended to, the resource will never be found.  You can search for R.java to see the values for your app:

```
public static final class string {
     public static final int about_open_source_heading=0x7f060013;
     public static final int about_open_source_list=0x7f060014;
}
```

If you have hard coded strings that depend on a specific value, maybe you can do something like this:

```
switch ( id ) {
   case 12345: 
      parkAddr = R.string.stg_ParkAddress_12345;
      break;
   case 12346: 
      parkAddr = R.string.stg_ParkAddress_12346;
      break;
}
```

Comment: Gary Bak, why are you accessing the `public static final class string`?

Comment: @FilipeOS - that was just a sample of what the `R.java` file looks like.  When you use the constants R.string.stg_ParkAddress_X you are referencing the final in that file/class.

Answer (score 2):

String resource can not be changed at runtime. You can save the string in SharedPreference which you can modify and save for further uses.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to edit the string resources programmatically,Do another class and have your strings placed in this class and access during run time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate it with `id`

```
String parkAdd = getString(R.string.stg_ParkAddress) + id;
```

Comment: No because it will fetch my string and not the stg_ParkAddress_X